# App installed with NSIS Installer does not start

Tags: c#, wpf, nsis

My app was developed with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 C# WPF .NET Framework 4.7, and the installer with NSIS 3.05 MUI2. The development file directory is on an external drive because I had to carry out the development on 2 different computers with the Windows 10 Pro x64 Build 19041.746 operating system. MS VS 2019 as well as .NET Framework 4.8 is installed on both computers.

All files from the file directory ... / App_Name.bin.Release have been copied into the installation directory by the NSIS installer

My app works error-free within the development system (debug as well as release). The installation with the NSIS installer on my development computers was also error-free.

## The problem:

As long as my external drive is connected to a computer via USB, my app starts without any problems on it, but if the external drive is removed, my app no longer starts! Double click at the desktop icon as well as at the exe file has no effect.

In contrast, the uninstaller can always be started without any problems!

I can't find any explanation for this behavior. Can someone help me there? I suspect, something is missing from the installer, but what?

Comment: Have you checked if all shortcuts you create point to files in $instdir?

Comment: What about some dependencies? Maybe some of them are missing so the app does not start correctly. Check the Event Log for details.

Comment: Hi Slappy, after I followed up on your hint and evaluated the Windows EventLog, I found your suspicion about a missing file confirmed, but the event log did not tell which file was missing. So I gradually tested the files of my project until I actually found the missing file. That solved my problem. Thanks for your hint.